# Howto hide launcher to see only wallpaper

Tags: android

I'd like to hide application launcher programatically so there is visible only my live wallpaper. In other words, I need to put my live wallpaper to foreground, just for some short time, so user can see an information on wallpaper and after short time period (2 sec for example) the launcher is again visible.
The same process is working when user locks a device. The launcher (including app icons and all widgets) is hidden and visible is only wallpaper and some screen-locker overlay such is time/date etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. However you can create your own Activity with the wallpaper them to show the live wallpaper behind it. Just make sure your Activity is empty and there you go :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can there is a programm called show off live wallpaper. This will hide everything else. http://www.androlib.com/android.application.net-jjc1138-android-showoff-pFAw.aspx
just use your barcode scanner on the QR screen and it will take you to the Market. It's free